# Capture image from video every 5 seconds, and save picutres using Python & OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

The person who is making the ocr program. I want to capture the image of the video every 5 seconds and inspect it in real time.

```
cap = cv2.VieoCapture(0)

while(True)
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imwrite('Test.png'),frame,params=[cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION,2]
    ocrcheck()    #Function to read 'Test.png' and check with ocr program
```

I want to get a frame in real time every 5 seconds, save it and print the saved image to the ocr program.
Please tell me the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use cv2.waitKey(delay_in_ms) or time.sleep(delay_in_seconds) to sleep for a given amount of time. 
Consider also the following: your ocrcheck() function and cv2.imwrite will spend some time, so it's better to sleep not for 5 seconds, but for (5 - time_spent), where time_spent is the time spent on calling these two functions. Example:

```
while(True)
    start_time = time.time()

    ret,frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imwrite('Test.png'),frame,params=[cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION,2]
    ocrcheck()    #Function to read 'Test.png' and check with ocr program

    spent = time.time() - start_time # how much you spent on calling functions above

    time.sleep(5 - spent) # sleep for a rest of time
```